# Enabled the button only if the picturebox have a picture on it

Tags: c#, winforms, image, picturebox

I want to enabled the button only if the picturebox on windows forms have a picture on it. Otherwise, the button will remains false.

I already tried this below code, but when the picturebox contains a picture, the button won't enabled at all (the button enabled is true by default)

```
if (pictureBox1 == null || pictureBox1.Image == null)
            {
                this.button2.Enabled = false;
            }

            else if (pictureBox1 != null || pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                this.button2.Enabled = true;
            }

if (pictureBox1 == null || pictureBox1.BackgroundImage == null)
            {
                this.button2.Enabled = false;
            }

            else
            {
                this.button2.Enabled = true;
            }
```

Your answer much appreciated!

Comment: are you sure you are using the `Image` property and NOT using the `BackgroundImage` property?

Comment: Your second else if test is redundant as in order to reach that check, both picturebox1 can't be null as well as its image cannot be null

Comment: @Selman22: on form1_load sir.

Comment: @bwtrent: what suppose I used then?

Comment: @Kaoru, all I am saying is make sure that the property you set is the one you check. If you set `BackgroundImage` check against it and not `Image`. I have made mistakes like that myself and got super frustrated...

Answer (score 2):

If that code is executed on the `Load` event of the form and the `PictureBox` is empty at that point then the `Button` will be disabled.  If you load an `Image` later then you would have to execute the code again.  There is no event raised when an `Image` is loaded so you should simply write a method for the purpose:

```
private void SetPictureBoxImage(Image img)
{
    this.pictureBox1.Image = img;
    this.SetButtonEnabledState();
}

private void SetButtonEnabledState()
{
    this.button2.Enabled = (this.pictureBox1.Image != null);
}
```

Whenever you want to set or clear the `Image`, call that first method.  You can call that second method on the `Load` event of the form as well, in case you set the `Image` in the designer, which would bypass the `SetPictureBoxImage` method.